# Intuition behind $\frac{a}{b}$ mod $(c)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, fractions

I read somewhere that $\frac{1}{3}$ mod $(11) = 4$ mod $(11)$. I tried adding $11$ to $\frac{1}{3}$ but that didn't seem to help in any way. I was simply unable to grasp the idea of what $\frac{a}{b}$ mod $(c)$ really means. Does it have a specific definition like $a^{\frac{b}{c}}$ which is $\sqrt[c]{a^{b}}$ ? I would appreciate any answers/hints to go from $\frac{1}{3}$ mod $(11)$ to $4$ mod $(11)$ and the intuition behind $\frac{a}{b}$ mod $(c)$.

Comment: It's important to realize that when talking of "$\frac 13$" in modulo arithmetic it has *nothing* to do with the value $0.3333....$.  In modulo arithmetic there are no fractions.  Just modulo *classes* of integers.  $\frac 13$ in modulo arithmetic refers simply to $[x]$, the class of integers so that $3x \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$.  So add $11$ to $1$ untill you get something that is divisible by $3$.  $3x \equiv 1\equiv 1+ 11\equiv 12\pmod {11}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dfrac 13$ is an abuse of notations, what we are talking about is the inverse of $3$ noted $3^{-1}$ which is effectively $4$ due to the fact that:

$3\times 4\equiv 12\equiv (11+1)\equiv 1\pmod{11}\iff 3^{-1}\equiv 4\pmod{11}$

When $$uv\equiv vu\equiv 1\pmod{m}$$

We say that $v$ is the inverse of $u$, every number such that $\gcd(u,m)=1$ has an inverse modulo $m$ and it is noted $u^{-1}$ rather than $\dfrac 1u$.

When you need to solve $ax\equiv b\pmod{m}$ then instead of dividing by $a$ and have $x=\dfrac ba$, you multiply by the inverse of $a$ in $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$ if it exists.

$$ax\equiv b\pmod{m}\iff x\equiv a^{-1}ax\equiv a^{-1}b\pmod{m}$$

But when $\gcd(a,m)\neq 1$ then $a$ has no inverse, same as $0$ as no inverse in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: *Please* strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).  Use of fractional notation here is not an "abuse" of notation - rather it is standard notation in abstract algebra for elements of rings of fractions and localizations.

Comment: @BillDubuque Apologies for the duplicate question! I will strive to do better research and ensure that the questions I ask in the future are completely original.

Comment: @learning123 Not to worry, we were all newbies at one time or another. If you still have questions then please leave commemts here or in the dupes. Happy modular journeys.